# Cruise Control.net Ms Build Task setting XML output Name

Tags: msbuild-task

We are running version  1.5.6755.1 of CruiseControl.net. Here is our block that executes a build

```
<!-- MSBuild of Source Code  -->
  <cb:define name="BuildOneProject-block">
    <msbuild>
      <executable>C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe</executable>
      <!-- Directory where source is -->
      <workingDirectory>D:\CC\$(AppName)\Source</workingDirectory>
      <!-- Solution file to be built-->
      <projectFile>D:\CC\$(AppName)\Source\$(ProjectName)\$(ProjectName).csproj</projectFile>
      <buildArgs>/noconsolelogger /p:SolutionName=\$(AppName) /p:SolutionDir=D:\CC\$(AppName)\Source /p:Configuration=$(ReleaseOrDebug) /v:diag</buildArgs>
      <targets>Build</targets>
      <timeout>900</timeout>
      <logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
    </msbuild>
  </cb:define>
```

When this run it generates a file with a name like..

msbuild-results-5cb1c8fa-1bba-4e97-a0b1-b2bf637308dc.xml

Is there another tag on the MsBuild task that allows me to name the xml file?   Is there an argument to the Logger that allows me to specify the name of the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it from the documentation.  If the name matters, you might be able to use `<exec>` instead and specify everything.

Answer (score 0):

From

http://groups.google.com.ag/group/ccnet-user/browse_thread/thread/1aa2a6a30fd715c3

It looks like the logger will take one input which is the output file name.   I tried changing

```
<logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll</logger>
```

To

```
<logger>C:\Program Files\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MsBuild.dll , msbuild-results-$(ProjectName)</logger>
```

But still no joy